# Filter looping issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with this code that is suppsed to get data from another workbook and specific worksheet. It's supposed to sort and filter out data that is in Column C when I enter a specific data that I enter on my workbook. The code is working up until the sort and filter part and it seems like it's duplicating the data on my workbook instead of just filtering and pulling the data needed. Here is the code I will separate it in parts for better understanding.
Beginning of code that opens the other workbook:

The 3rd to last part of the code is what is highlighted in the debugging process, the "workbooks(mname) part towards the end.

```
Workbooks(mname).Sheets(msheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Master_RRR.xlsm").Sheets("MGPR1").Range("A1")
    I = 17
    Do While Workbooks("Master_RRR.xlsm").Sheets("Master log").Cells(17, "Y").Value <> ""
    mbank = Workbooks("Master_RRR.xlsm").Sheets("Master log").Cells(17, "Y").Value
    match = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(mbank, Workbooks(mname).Sheets(msheet).Range("C1:C" & LastRow), 0)
    repeat = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(mname).Sheets(msheet).Range("C1:C" & LastRow), mbank)
    till = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Master_RRR.xlsm").Sheets("MGPR1").Range("C:C"))
   Workbooks(mname).Sheets(msheet).Range(Cells(match, "C"), Cells(match + repeat - 1, LastCol)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Master_RRR.xlsm").Sheets("MGPR1").Range("A" & till + 1)
   I = I + 1
   Loop
```

Here is the beginning of the code:

```
Sub getdata()
Dim mastername As String
Dim count As Long
Dim match As Long
Dim repeat As Long
Dim path As String
Dim status As String
Dim name As String
Dim mpath As String
Dim cpath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim mbank As String
Dim mname As String

mpath = Sheets("Master log").Cells(14, "Y").Value
mname = Sheets("Master log").Cells(15, "Y").Value
msheet = Sheets("Master log").Cells(16, "Y").Value
Sheets("MGPR1").Range("A1:AA50000").ClearContents

name = Application.ActiveWorkbook.name
cpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"

Windows(name).Activate

'--open Management report  workbook if not already open
If CheckFileIsOpen(mname) = False Then
Workbooks.Open mpath & mname
End If
'-------------------------------------------

Windows(mname).Activate
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

 If ws.Visible = True Then

 End If

 Next ws

    Sheets(msheet).Select

    'select full data

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
       ' LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       LastCol = 22
    End With

    '--------------------- put filter

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("K2").Select

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(msheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(msheet).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("H5").Select
```

Comment: When you define "name" as the ActiveWorkbook, when would it not be active to need to activate it?   I like what you are doing, especially in the top portion.

Comment: Once the code transitions to opening the other workbook (mname) it's no longer the active workbook that has the code.

Comment: I am referring to name=Application.ActiveWorkbook.name then Windows(name).Activate right after it.